# Draw on Bitmap but on specific parts of it

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-canvas, android-drawable

I have a picture of a tennis racket in my fragment [like this](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB10KlMIXXXXXalXFXXq6xXFXXXq/-font-b-Kason-b-font-CARVEL-U3-font-b-Badminton-b-font-font-b-Racket.jpg).

I will receive X / Y coordinates from the main part of the racket lets say I will get x/y from this image:

[image: this image]

I have no idea how can I DRAW (red dots) on the other image with the full racket after i receive the x/y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method to overlay an image at specified x,y cords:

```
private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap sourceMap,Bitmap locationDrawable,int x, int y) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceMap.getWidth(), sourceMap.getHeight(), sourceMap.getConfig());
        Bitmap bmp2small =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(locationDrawable, (int) Math.round(locationDrawable.getWidth() * .25), (int) Math.round(locationDrawable.getHeight() * .25), true);
        int bmp2width = bmp2small.getWidth();
        int bmp2height = bmp2small.getHeight();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(sourceMap, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2small, (float) x - (bmp2width / 2), (float) y - bmp2height, null);


        bmp2small.recycle();


        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

Comment: Yes but i dont know how to get X/Y coordinates to the first image, https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB10KlMIXXXXXalXFXXq6xXFXXXq/-font-b-Kason-b-font-CARVEL-U3-font-b-Badminton-b-font-font-b-Racket.jpg

Comment: you know the size /resolution of the picture, so you can figure it out based on those dimensions